# Sharepoint re-ordering list

Tags: excel, sharepoint-calendar, reporting

I've got a SharePoint Calendar that i've linked to an Excel document and it's currently pulling the data through and dumping it in a table and also a chart on another sheet (But that's irrelevant!)

When it comes into the table it's giving me some HTML Code  Tags around the details like this

```
<div>Example Test<br></div>
```

It also gives me some other tags sometimes such as:

```
 <div>Change into Pre Prod </div><div>&#160;</div><div>See CHG XXXXX</div>
```

Does anyone know how to stop the tags coming through into excel?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may stumble across this...

I had to create several macros in excel and got them to run when loading excel which meant the end user never saw them!